# What am I doing wrong? I need VBA help to change the data series for Excel stacked column chart

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the last/bottom row of a chart's data, which gets refreshed by another chunk of VBA code. This is for a stacked bar chart on a worksheet; the chart's data is on different worksheet in the same workbook.

The chart's data gets refreshed via an ADODB call to a SQL Server database. Specifically, each time the data gets refreshed, I use VBA code to clear the prior rows, and then insert the new data. The new dataset will often have a different number of rows than the prior dataset: the new dataset might have more or fewer rows than the old dataset.

My problem is that when I try changing the chart's source data, nothing happens to the chart, and I don't get any error.

Below is the relevant VBA snippet (where iLastRow is set earlier in the VBA, based on the number of rows in the new dataset).

- iLastRow will always be greater than 2, usually 30, 60, 90, etc.
- Column A is a list of dates (mm/dd/yyyy), and columns C-G are numeric values.

```
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Set myChart = Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 22")
    myChart.Activate
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Charts Data'!$A$1:$A$" & CStr(iLastRow) & ",'Charts 
    Data'!$C$1:$G$" & CStr(iLastRow))
```

I **don't** want to re-create the chart each time the dataset is refreshed, since the only thing that needs to be updated for the chart is the row number of the bottom/last row for the chart data (iLastRow in my VBA snippet).

What am I doing wrong, and/or is there a preferred way to adjust the chart's data?

Comment: The preferred way is to have a QueryTable on the sheet that performs the query, which then resizes its result range correctly. Alternatively, make sure that refreshing VBA code resizes the result range correctly (by inserting the rows in the middle). In either case, the chart will pick up the new range automatically.

Comment: I ended up recording several macros so I could see how Excel defined the chart's source data, changed the existing chart's source data, etc., and ended up with a simple fix:
```ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 22").Activate  
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Metrics Data").Range("A1:A" & CStr(iLastRow) & ",C1:G" & CStr(iLastRow))
```